# Optimizing unexplainably slow MySQL query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, subquery, aggregate-functions

I'm losing hair on a stupid query. First, I would explain what's its goal. I have a set of values fetched every hour and stored in the DB. These values can increase or stay equal with time. This query extracts the **latest value day by day** for latest 60 days (I have twins query for extract lastest value by weeks and months, they are similar). The query is self explanatory:

```
SELECT l.value AS value
FROM atable AS l
WHERE l.time = (
                  SELECT MAX(m.time)
                  FROM atable AS m
                  WHERE DATE(l.time) = DATE(m.time) 
                  LIMIT 1
               )
ORDER BY l.time DESC 
LIMIT 60
```

It looks no special. But it's extremely slow (> 30 secs), considering `time` is an index and table contains less than 5000 rows. And I'm sure the problem is with sub-query.

Where is the noob mistake?

---

**Update 1**: Same situation if I avoid `MAX()` using `SELECT m.time ... ORDER BY m.time DESC`.

**Update 2**: Seems is not a problem with `DATE()` function called to many times. I've tried to create a calculated field `day DATE`. The `UPDATE atable SET day = DATE(time)` runs in less than 2secs. The modified query, with `l.day = m.day` (no functions!), runs in the same exactly time as before.

---

Comment: Have you tried using a join instead of a subquery? Joins tend to optimize better than subqueries.

Comment: I don't know how to transform this type of (sub)queries into JOINs :(

Comment: Ok, am I missing something?  Let me re-ask the question... you want the maximum time entry from the "aTable" on a per Day Basis for the last 60 days?  THREE questions.  1-- Does the "aTable" have an auto-increment key on it for every new entry being added?  and 2-- are the timestamps always sequentially greater than the prior? and 3-- is there an index on the time field (and confirm it is a full date/time field).

Comment: @DRapp **1)** Yes, `id INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`. **2)** Yes, I said *These values can increase or stay equal with time*. **3)** Yes, `time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. You can see full table structure in some links in comments to answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue I see is using `DATE()` on the left of the expression in the `WHERE` clause. Using the function `DATE()` on both sides of the `WHERE` expression explicitly prevents MySQL from using an index on the date field. Instead, it must scan all rows to apply the function on each row.

Instead of this:

```
WHERE DATE(l.time) = DATE(m.time)
```

Try something like this:

```
WHERE l.time BETWEEN
  DATE_SUB(m.date, INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(m.date) SECOND)
  AND DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(m.date, INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(m.date) SECOND), INTERVAL 86399 SECOND)
```

Maybe you know of a better way to turn `m.date` into a range like `2012-02-09 00:00:00` and `2012-02-09 23:59:59` than the above example, but the idea is that you want to keep the left side of the expression as the raw column name, `l.time` in this case, and give it a range in the form of two constants (or two expressions that can be converted to constants) on the right side.

**EDIT**

I'm using your pre-calculated `day` field:

```
SELECT *
FROM atable a
WHERE a.time IN
(SELECT MAX(time)
FROM atable
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day DESC
LIMIT 60)
```

At least here, the inner query is only ran once, and then a binary search is done with the `IN` cluase. You're still scanning the table, but just once, and the advantage of the inner query being run just once will probably make a huge dent.

If you know that you have values for every day, you could improve that inner query by adding a `WHERE` clause, limiting it to the last 60 calendar days, and losing the `LIMIT 60`. Make sure that `day` and `time` are indexed.

Comment: I've tried to create a calculated field `day DATE`. The `UPDATE atable SET day = DATE(time)` runs in less than 2secs. The modified query, with `l.day = m.day` (no functions!) runs in the same ultra-long time!!! :( Then, the problem is not on `DATE()` function?

Comment: Your subquery is also causing a full table scan because it has to be evaluated for each row. I will try to provide full query in a few.

Comment: @lorenzo, I've provided the full query, but using your pre-calculated field. That should be pretty fast. Maybe I'll try to come up with something better tomorrow. I have to scoot.

Comment: Ok, now that's a lot better. However, to force inner query to run only once, I had to wrap it inside a `SELECT * FROM ( ... ) AS tmp` temporary table; otherwise it runs as before and also don't let me use `LIMIT` *(that's the first time I see the error "LIMIT not allowed in IN sub queries", lol)*... Now I have to check if result set is exactly the same.

Comment: Additionally to what I've just said about wrapping inner query, now there is no need for the calculated field. I can use `GROUP BY DATE(time)` with no significant performance loss. Finally, ~40secs -> ~0.1secs **:)**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using MAX(m.time) do the following in the sub-select

```
SELECT m.time
FROM table AS m
WHERE DATE(l.time) = DATE(m.time)
ORDER BY m.time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This might help speed up the query since it is giving the query parser an alternative

However one other piece i noticed is you are using the DATE(l.time) and DATE(m.time) which if your index is not created on DATE(m.time) then you will not be using the index and hence could cause slowness.

Comment: +1 It will be necessary to perform a conversion for each time value that is compared

Comment: Quite the same running time (0.75x) using `ORDER` instead of `MAX`... In order to create an index on DATE(time) I suppose I have to store a calculated field in the table itself, right?

Comment: In postgresql you would create index on DATE(time) for the table and this syntax would work and create the necessary index. However i am not sure if MySql has that capability or not.

Comment: In fact, it seems I can't. Anyway I can always create a calculated field and place an index on it. Doing that and using it in query, anyway, do not solve the problem. You can read comments about it on Marcus Adams answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the feedback answer, if the entries are sequentially added via date/time, directly correlated to the auto-increment ID, who cares about the TIME... get the auto-inc number for exact, non-ambiguous join

```
select
      A1.AutoID,
      A1.time,
      A1.Value
   from
      ( select date( A2.time ) as SingleDate,
               max( A2.AutoID ) as MaxAutoID
           from aTable A2
           where date( A2.Time ) >= date( date_sub( now(), interval 60 day ))
           group by date( A2.time ) ) into MaxPerDate
      JOIN aTable A1
         on MaxPerDate.MaxAutoID = A1.AutoID
   order by
      A1.AutoID DESC
```

Comment: Thank you DRapp. I've just solved with a complete query rewrite. I'm sure your answer improve performance, but anyway query logic remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "explain" statement to get mysql to tell you what it's doing.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  l.value AS value
        FROM    table AS l
        WHERE   l.time = (
                   SELECT MAX(m.time)
                   FROM   table AS m
                   WHERE  DATE(l.time) = DATE(m.time) LIMIT 1
                )
        ORDER BY l.time DESC LIMIT 60
```

That should at least give you an insight where to look further.

Comment: I tried using `EXPLAIN`, but I saw nothing strange. Here you are the **[output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LELE5TuW)**.

Comment: @lorenzo-s The outer query is filesorting without indexes on ~8k rows, so doesn't look to be using the index. What hardware are you running on?

Comment: Dev machine (2.3Ghz x2, 2GB RAM) is running MySQL 5.5.8 on Windows XP. Production machine (that is 2x faster running that query) is a hosting running MySQL 5.0.92 on Linux.

Comment: I agree, having said that I dont understand why it should be taking so long.  Using functions in where clauses normally causes issues as mysql will have to evaluate every record, run it through the function to determine if it should be included in the resultset or not.  Try and use "BETWEEN" instead of date(x) = date(y)

Comment: @lorenzo-s As per my answer, try changing the engine to InnoDB and running the EXPLAIN again to see if it stops filesorting and starts using an index.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on `time`, I would suggest getting `TOP 1` instead of `MAX` as follows:

```
SELECT  l.value AS value
FROM    table AS l
WHERE   l.time = (
               SELECT TOP 1 m.time
               FROM   table AS m
               ORDER BY m.time DESC LIMIT 1
             )
ORDER BY l.time DESC LIMIT 60
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer query is using a filesort without indexes.
Try changing to InnoDB engine to see if it improves things.

Doing a quick test:

```
mysql> show create table atable\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: atable
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `atable` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `t` (`t`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT id FROM atable AS l WHERE l.t = (                   SELECT MAX(m.t)                   FROM atable AS m                   WHERE DATE(l.t) = DATE(m.t)                    LIMIT 1                ) ORDER BY l.t DESC  LIMIT 50;
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | l     | index | NULL          | t    | 4       | NULL |   50 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | m     | index | NULL          | t    | 4       | NULL |   50 | Using where; Using index |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

After changing to MyISAM:

mysql> explain SELECT id FROM atable AS l WHERE l.t = (                   SELECT MAX(m.t)                   FROM atable AS m                   WHERE DATE(l.t) = DATE(m.t)                    LIMIT 1                ) ORDER BY l.t DESC  LIMIT 50;
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | l     | ALL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   50 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | m     | index | NULL          | t    | 4       | NULL |   50 | Using where; Using index    |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Same execution time. See **[`EXPLAIN` output](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gESHmDib)** and **[`CREATE TABLE` code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Dz3tD46S)** (columns name are in Italian).

Comment: Do you get the same output from EXPLAIN on both MySQL servers?

Comment: On hosting I do not have InnoDB. However I'm sure on dev server I have a real InnoDB engine, I use transactions a lot.